# How to get new iOS SDK in Xcode 9.2?

Tags: ios, xcode, ios-simulator

My app patch binary was just rejected by Apple and crash logs show that it was tested against iOS 11.2.5, but my latest simulator is 11.2. All of my local UI Tests and Unit Tests passed.

I'd like to test and fix this, but I cannot get iOS 11.2.5 simulators. The traditional approach is to go to devices and download new simulators in Xcode. However, even my most recent simulators (11.2) do not show up here. And no amount of "Check and Install" makes 11.2.5 appear as a choice.
[image: download simulator screen]

**Please help. Here is what I have tried.**

- I tried relaunching Xcode and restarting my mac
- I tried to follow the advice from [Hacker Noon - Manually install iOS Simulators](https://hackernoon.com/manually-install-ios-simulators-in-xcode-f7e4bbe50753). I downloaded the iOS 11.2.5 builds for iPhone X and iPad Air2. My downloaded files are .ipsw (which keeps trying to open in iTunes) but even after moving the downloaded files to the cache, they do not show up in Xcode.
- I tried updating my os. I was running Sierra. Now I am running High Sierra, new XCode tools were downloaded automatically on launch. However, no new simulators.
- I also went back to developer.apple to look for a whole 11.2.5 download and could not find one. On the [main developer download page](https://developer.apple.com/download/) the only whole download is 11.3 beta. Searching on the [See More Downloads](https://developer.apple.com/download/more/) is empty for "ios 11.2.5" and just "11.2.5"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you're using Xcode 9.2 you have installed the SDK for iOS 11.2 already. You can prove that by opening *System Preferences -> General -> About* in the simulator. Thus, Xcode will not display n item for downloading it. The SDKs are also only for minor releases. There are no SDKs for different patch versions.

If you actually have a bug that occurs in this version, you should get a corresponding device and test it for it. I suspect, however, that this is due to the differences between simulator and real hardware.

Comment: Thank you. Yes. I know I have 11.2, but I don't have 11.2.5. Is there no way to get it?  Everything works on 11.2 (simulated- I can't test all real). FWIW -
 Between the released version on the app store now and the patch version, the only changes were to autolayout constraints, so I was very surprised to see crash reports anyways because I did UI Tests for all devices.

Comment: As I wrote, Xcode doesn't support patch versions for simulators. So, you can't get 11.2.5 for simulator. I highly appreciate you to test that on a real device. If you're creating a TestFlight version, you might ask friends, relatives or colleagues for help. The differences between devices and simulator are greater than the differences between 11.2 and 11.2.5.

Comment: oh...phew - so I was just crazy. I guess having 11.0.3 and such confused me!